# Itemize environment has wrong indentation in a hanging caption?

Tags: captions, indentation, enumerate, koma-script, itemize

I want to use the itemize environment inside a hanging caption but the indentation is just as in the main body. I'd like to have the listing indented from the hanging caption.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
\begin{itemize}
    \item bar
\end{itemize}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
\caption[foo bar]{foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
    foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
  \begin{itemize}
       \item this listing belongs to the caption
       \item but looks as if it was part of the body
  \end{itemize}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely that such a setup might be an exclusion rather than the norm. So, set the items manually using `\textbullet` and appropriate `itemize`-like spacing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 

\begin{itemize}
  \item bar
\end{itemize}

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
  \caption[foo bar]{foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
    foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo

    \textbullet \hspace{\labelsep}this listing belongs to the caption

    \textbullet \hspace{\labelsep}but looks as if it was part of the body
  }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You can also set the content in a `tabularx` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{caption,tabularx}

\begin{document}

foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 

\begin{itemize}
  \item bar
\end{itemize}

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
  \caption[foo bar]{foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
    foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo

    \medskip

    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{\phantom{\figurename~\thefigure:~}} l @{\hspace{\labelsep}} X @{}}
      \textbullet & this listing belongs to the caption \\
      \textbullet & but looks as if it was part of the body
    \end{tabularx}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! I just realized that I wasn't paying attention to the details when asking my question: I am actually using the `enumerate` environment. (The figure contains numbered process steps I am describing).

Comment: Of course, your second solution does the trick neatly for numbers instead of `\textbullet`.
Perfect, many thanks!